# uniform values and OpenGL shaders

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, opengl-es, shader

so I have a little animation I guess in openGL in a program I'm coding with shaders in QT.

My animation changed as a function of the time. To calculate time I used a Timer in a Slot that would repeatedly update the time.

I have a Qwidget, my vertex shader is very plain so I wont include the code.

now for my fragment shader:

```
 QOpenGLShader *fshader = new QOpenGLShader(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, this);
 const char *fsrc =
        "uniform float time;\n"
        "in vec4 coordinates;\n"
        "out vec4 outcolor;\n"
        "void main(void)\n"
        "{\n"
        "   float l,z=time;"
        "   outcolor=vec4(coordinates * time);" //<- pretend i did something with time here
        "}\n";
fshader->compileSourceCode(fsrc);
```

and then my time update method:

```
void MyWidget::updateTime()
{
    float seconds;
    seconds = (float) ((double) clock() - startTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    program->setUniformValue("time", (float) seconds / (float) CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

}
```

and finally how I use it:

```
 timeTimer=new QTimer();    
QObject::connect(timeTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()),this, SLOT(updateTime()));
timeTimer->start(20);
```

however when I run my program it compiles and executes but the timer doesn't update, no matter how long I wait. My hunch is that I am not using a good way to update the time in my shader, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know how this Qt signal stuff works, but you'll need to make sure that the `updateTime()` method is called in the same thread that you're rendering from. Otherwise there's no current OpenGL context when you're trying to set the uniform value.

Comment: i attempted to use glGetUniformLocation() but I dont know how to find a program's handle. Does my code look valid at first glance? I was worried that simply calling program->setUniformValue was not enough since the program has both the vertex and fragment shader... @RetoKoradi

Comment: The call itself looks fine. I suspect that your signal handler is either invoked in a different thread, or your program is not the active program, when you call `setUniformValue()`. It would seem safer to just store the updated time in a class member, and then make the `setUniformValue()` call during your redraw. Not sure how Qt handles redraws, but you might also have to trigger a redraw if it does not continually redraw by itself.

Comment: Do you need to bind your program before you setUniformValue in your updateTime method?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are updating the time correctly but you are not re-drawing your widget. You should call the function that re-draw the widget at the end of updateTime (I think the name of that function is repaint()).

Comment: thanks, I tried adding an update and repaint but I dont think that's the problem. I guess a better question might be how should I debug this? I dont know of any way to step through the shader code that I gave